# Deduplication algorithm logic

Tags: python

could you please help me find the error in my logic? The function doesn't work well and I can't figure out why. The instructions are: Write a function remove_duplicates that takes in a list and removes elements of the list that are the same. Do not modify the list you take as input! Instead, return a new list. For example: remove_duplicates([1,1,2,2]) should return [1,2].

For [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7] I'm getting this output [1, 2, 5, 7], which is good. However, for [4, 9, 9, 4] the output is [9, 9, 4], which is wrong. I can't find out what the problem is. I started learning programming a few weeks ago, so I'm a novice. Thanks!

My code:

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    nl = list(l)
    i = 0    
    while i <= len(nl)-2:
        j = i + 1
        while j <= len(nl)-1:
            if nl[i] == nl[j]:
                nl.remove(nl[j])
            else:
                j += 1
        i += 1
    return nl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the line

```
nl.remove(nl[j])
```

You want to remove the item at index j. What this line actually does is remove the *first occurrence* of the *value* contained at index j.

Instead, try

```
del nl[j]
```

---

**Edit:**

Let's trace your example, `remove_duplicates([4,9,9,4])`:

```
nl = [4, 9, 9, 4]
i = 0

j = 1
nl[0] != nl[1]

j = 2
nl[0] != nl[2]

j = 3
nl[0] == nl[3]
```

At this point, you want to get rid of `nl[3]` by calling

```
nl.remove(nl[3])
```

but see what happens:

```
>>> [4, 9, 9, 4].remove(4)      # you expect [4, 9, 9, {deleted}]
[9, 9, 4]                       # but get    [{deleted}, 9, 9, 4]
```

which causes further issues by shifting the array - `i` and `j` no longer point at the same items.

The cause is simple:

```
>>> help(list.remove)
L.remove(value) -> None -- remove first occurrence of value.
                                    ^^                 ^^
```

you are telling it to remove a *value*, not a *location*.

If instead you do

```
nl = [4, 9, 9, 4]
del nl[3]          # delete a *location*, not a *value*     
                   # gives [4, 9, 9, {deleted}]
```

you get the result you were expecting.

Comment: This helped, but don't understand why. Could you elaborate a bit more on this?

Answer (score 2):

You want to utilize a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). A set will remove duplicates

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    return list(set(l))


l_1 = [1,1,2,2]
l_2 = remove_duplicates(l_1)

print l_1
print l_2
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Alternatively, with your other list:

```
[4, 9, 9, 4]
[9, 4]
```

---

Notice that the function wraps `set` in a `list`, otherwise you would get a `set` back, instead of a new `list`.

Answer (score 2):

in python we have `set` to remove duplication:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7]
>>> set(a)
set([1, 2, 5, 7])
```

in your code if you backtrack:

```
0 i          # here i is 0 
1 j          # here j is 0
4 duplicate element   first duplicate element found at last that is 4, but removed from front
1 i           # now list is [9,9,4]  but i is 1 and j is 2
2 j
[9, 9, 4]
```

so there is not match for 9 and 9 , so it not been removed

so in your code if you put `del(nl[j])` , it will work fine.

Comment: This is not incorrect, but it should be noted that this returns a `set` not a `list`, like the questioner asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into deduplication via converting the list object into a `set`.

```
my_list = [4, 9, 9, 4]
deduped = list(set(my_list))
print deduped  # prints [9, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

For `[4, 9, 9, 4]` if you want `[4, 9]` to be the output, other answers that just use `list(set(a))` will not preserve the order.

To preserve the order use:

```
def remove_duplicates(l):
    s = set()
    o = []
    for i in l:
        if i not in s:
            s.add(i)
            o.append(i)
    return o
```

See that:

```
>>> remove_duplicates([4, 9, 9, 4])
[4, 9]
```